# Infura: certificate has expired error when deploying on Rinkeby

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, infura, rinkeby, etherlime

I was trying to deploy some contracts on Rinkeby using Infura, and got the following error:

```
Error: certificate has expired\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1088:34)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:666:8)' }
```

(The complete stack trace is at the bottom of the question.)

I'm using a deploy script as so:

```
if (network == 'rinkeby') {
        // Overriding default config for rinkeby test net
        defaultConfigs.chainId = 4;
        // Setting private key for this network
        secret = process.env.DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY_RINKEBY;
        // Setting the RPC
        RPC = `https:/rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY_RINKEBY}`;

        console.log("Deploying to Rinkeby network");
}
```

This script is using Etherlime's tools (elsewhere in the script, I'm not bringing it all since it seems to work, as you'll see in a minute that I could deploy on local RPC using it), and as you can assume `dotenv` for the environmental variables, which as far as I can tell, are set properly.

In the end I ended up spinning up a local Rinkeby node and deployed using the same script from local - I just changed the RPC variable to hit `localhost`, and that worked fine. (So no problems with the Etherlime, as far as I can tell.)

What is going wrong here?

#### Appendix

Here's the whole stack trace, with some details (like the actual Infura API key) edited out:

```
➜ yarn deploy:rinkeby
yarn run v1.22.5
$ etherlime deploy --network=rinkeby --runs=500
Compilation finished successfully
Deploying to Rinkeby network
Deployer set to deploy from address: 0x...

JSONRPC Deployer Network: https:/rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...

Deploying contract: Library_Token
{ Error: invalid response - 0
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/x/code/project/Blockchain/node_modules/etherlime-lib/node_modules/ethers/utils/web.js:84:29)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/home/x/code/project/Blockchain/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/home/x/code/project/Blockchain/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.handleError (/home/x/code/project/Blockchain/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:532:5)
    at ClientRequest.errorHandler (/home/x/code/project/Blockchain/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:459:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
  statusCode: 0,
  responseText:
   'Error: certificate has expired\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1088:34)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:666:8)' }
Your deployment script finished with failure!

Here is your report:

Done in 32.09s.
```

Thanks for reading, and super thanks if you took the time to write an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing a `/` in your URL. The following line should have `https://` and not `https:/`.

`RPC = 'https:/rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY_RINKEBY}';`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that - I feel like a idiot. Thanks for answering a typo kindly.